# 2to3 conversion for strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2to3

I have written a small Qt-based text editor for Python code that I embed in my application. Now I am going to switch to Python 3 and I want to help the users of my app with converting their code. I know that `2to3` can do most of the conversion for files. However, I need an on-the-fly conversion, without touching the files on disk. I mean something like:

```
py3_code_str = convert2to3(py2_code_str)
```

Does anybody know how it can be achieved with `2to3` or `lib2to3`?

Comment: I guess the best workaround would be to write the string into a temporary file (with help of the tempfile module), apply 2to3 and read the content of the file back into your self-written editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `lib2to3` doesn't have stable interface, meaning it might change drastically.

Though, in case you don't really care about that, it might be possible (with minor changes) to use `from lib2to3.refactor import RefactoringTool` and continue on with its `refactor_string` method.

Comment: This was the approach I chose. I added in my own answer what worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me thanks to [plaes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34307708/724873):

```
from lib2to3.refactor import RefactoringTool, get_fixers_from_package
refactoring_tool = RefactoringTool(fixer_names=get_fixers_from_package('lib2to3.fixes'))
node3 = refactoring_tool.refactor_string(text2, 'script')
text3 = str(node3)
```

Answer (score -1):

That's really not what 2to3 is for.

You should be writing your code in such a way that it is compatible with both Python 2 and 3. The [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) library can help with that.

Comment: I am doing so. But users of my editor don't. This is why I need such tool.